# Create an Event when storage account is updated it will trigger an event and send a message in storage queue Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-queues

I want to create an Event Grid which will trigger an event to storage queue if any change occurs in Storage Account.

In short, if any storage account is updated it will trigger an event and send a message in storage queue - is this possible in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to the resource group. The document [Azure resource group as an Event Grid source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-resource-groups) described all details.

Also, have a look at the document [Storage queue as an event handler for Azure Event Grid events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-storage-queues) for receiving the filtered events emitted by resource group.

Answer (score 0):

There's no [Event source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview#event-sources) for S3.
One way is to use [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) and send a request to Event Grid:

[Post to custom topic for Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic)

Comment: Sorry I mean for the storage account 
if any storage account is updated it will trigger an event and send a message in storage queue???  is it  possible